# file upload doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC4 - mobile template

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using C# and ASP.NET MVC4 for a web application (mobile template).

Now I have the following code in my view:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
     { 
     <label for="file">Upload:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
     }
```

and this in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
        file.SaveAs(path);
        ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
        return View();
    }
```

when I run the application and try to upload a file, I get 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." message in Visual Studio.
But I know that the code above works fine in ASP.NET MVC3 as I've used it before.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What line is the error thrown on?

Comment: this line: string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

Comment: So, when you debug, the `file` param is null?

Comment: yes it is null, I have no idea why though

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted/

Comment: is it something in MVC4? because it works fine in MVC3...

Comment: ok so I created a brand new MVC4 project (internet template) and the code works fine in there. But not in MVC4 (mobile template). Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Your question is actually a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639756/mvc-4-beta-with-mobile-project-file-upload-does-not-work).  You might check out the answer there and see if it works for you.

Comment: Actually, according to the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688514/mvc-4-using-jquery-mobile-cannot-upload-file-using-post), @Jlsaak's answer below appears to be the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this attribute to your form: `data-ajax="false"`

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post,  new { enctype="multipart/form-data", data_ajax="false"})){
     <label for="file">Upload:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Comment: wow that worked! thank you. can you explain what the problem was?

Comment: `jQuery Mobile AJAXifies forms and as you already know it is not possible to upload files using AJAX. As a workaround you could add the data-ajax="false" attribute to your <form> element to prevent jQuery Mobile from hijacking it and using AJAX.` -- [source here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12690288/1317705)

Comment: @Forty-Two basically summed it up, here's another article: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-seems-to-clobber-ability-to-upload-files-via-forms

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `HttpPostedFileBase`, as the matter of fact you don't have to receive any parameters in your [HttpPost] Action. You can get your file from the request like this as long as your form is set to `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` (which you already do):

```
var file = Request.Files[0];
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the line above but i got this error " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"